# How to use GeoMet WMS with leaflet

Tags: leaflet, coordinate-systems, wms

I have been trying to make a WMS service work with leaflet.  I just want to use the standard CRS=EPSG:3857 which does seem to be supported by the service.  However I just cannot get the WMS layer to line up on the OpenStreetMap base layer.

This picture should line up over Canada.  It works in QGIS just fine.

[image]
Here is a code pen:https://codepen.io/keenedge/pen/dybWgbM

This is the doc page for the WMS I need to use.

I've tried setting `crs: L.CRS.EPS3857` in the map and in the WMS layer but it seems to have no effect.

Anyone now how to get this code pen working?

full code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mapid" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;"></div>
  <script>


    var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var osmAttrib = 'Map data © <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
    var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, { minZoom: 1, maxZoom: 19, attribution: osmAttrib });

    var wmsOptions = {
      layers: 'HRDPS.NORTH.PRES_WSPD.275',
      transparency: true,
      format: 'image/png',
      version: '1.3.0'
    }

    var url = 'https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet'
    var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms(url, wmsOptions);

    var myMap = L.map('mapid').setView([49, -123], 2);
    osm.addTo(myMap);
    wmsLayer.addTo(myMap);
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HRDPS.NORTH.PRES_WSPD.275` layer from that WMS server looks exactly the same in Leaflet than in QGis, when QGis is configured to display `EPSG:3857`:

[image: qgis screenshot]

You're doing nothing wrong. Note that other layers from the same WMS service do cover continental Canada, or the ocean, or some other area.

Comment: OMG! <slaps forehead> You are absolutely right. I was not even comparing apples to apples.Thank you so much for pointing out this silly mistake. You have saved me many more hours of hair pulling.